# Cast varhar to int jpql?

Tags: jpa, jpql

Hi i have this jpql string:

```
SELECT ap FROM AdvertProperty as ap WHERE  ap.name like 'price' and ap.value BETWEEN 100 and 200
```

The problem is that my price in database is stored as varchar ( because there are many another defferent properrties)
So what I need is some operator to convert it to integer.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no solution within JPQL, the alternative is to get the answer in String and change it to int by using `Integer.parseInt(String s)` [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

In EclipseLink 2.1 there is a function FUNC for calling database specific functions, for example:

```
FUNC('TO_NUMBER', ap.value)
```

From EclipseLink 2.4 and JPA 2.1 there is FUNCTION operator with the same functionality

Comment: i studied java... sorry :) I faced with the same problem and than found the solution. Hope it helps someone.